# A very weird behavior with Chrome and Edge, but not IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, azure-devops, throttling

We Azure DevOps Server 2020 on-prem. And I noticed that I cannot open more than just a few Azure DevOps builds in different Chrome tabs concurrently. Namely, here is what I am doing:

1. Navigate to an Azure DevOps build and wait until all the details are loaded.
2. Repeat step (1) for another build

What I have noticed is that after 5-1 tabs (sometimes I am "blessed" with 5 fully loaded tabs and sometimes I cannot have more than 1) no new tabs are able to load the build details. I am using builds as an example, could be PRs or other screens.

At first I thought we have some concurrency limit on the server, but we do not. Neither IIS nor the Sql Server serving the requests have any concurrency limit defined. But then, I have discovered an even weirder thing - this concurrency limit exists in Chrome and Edge, but not IE!

I do not want to make IE my default browser, I would prefer keeping Chrome. But this drives me crazy.

My current theory is that it has to with signalr. Azure DevOps frondend uses some kind of signalr implementation. Maybe Chrome and Edge are too "advanced" to handle it correctly? Or maybe IE does not handle it at all and so Azure DevOps server fallsback to something IE supports and as a result no throttling is experienced?

I am pretty lost here and have no idea how to troubleshoot it further. Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Initial inspection of the URLs visited from chrome vs IE shows a difference in signalr urls:

- IE: transport=webSockets
- Chrome: transport=serverSentEvents

Does it make sense to anyone? Could this difference explain why Chrome is unable to open more then 1-5 (1 sometimes happens in the evenings) tabs serving Azure DevOps Server 2020 web pages?

**EDIT 2**

Right at this moment the limit is 6. I have 6 tabs open on the same exact build, 7th is hanging. The Network tab in the browser shows it is being stuck on the very first server side request to `http://theserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/SharpTop/_build/results?buildId=1184073&view=logs&j=ca395085-040a-526b-2ce8-bdc85f692774`. No response at all. But if I close any of the other 6 tabs, it would load immediately.

**EDIT 3**

Posted on the MSFT Dev Community site - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-more-then-6-sometimes-less-tabs-of/1466416

Comment: you can use developer tools to diagnostic your browser to see what underlying communication/issues error are different from each browser. it might be some of the plugins/runtime version and engines not matching.

Comment: I looked. On the surface there are no errors. Ideally I should be able to compare the traffic with Chrome vs with IE. But there are so many requests. I will try to compare.

Comment: Both Chrome and IE export to HAR which can be open in Fiddler. This is a json file, seems to be. Would need some massaging to figure out the differences...

Comment: There is at least one site that suggests to be able to compare HAR files, but I cannot upload my HARs. I need a tool to download, but there do not seem to exist any.

Comment: Found one difference, do not know if it is significant - see **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 2):

Hi it could be some product issues around the supported browsers with policy/configuration on how http/https would handled, suggest you open up issue in the Azure DevOps Developer Community , and MS PG/support team can dive in to feedback you.

the similar has opened [Azure DevOps Server not loading properly](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-server-not-loading-properly/946502) that close to your descriptions here.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Here is the link - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-more-then-6-sometimes-less-tabs-of/1466416